# How to format time in calEvent

Tags: datetime, fullcalendar

I use a popup form to add events to the fullcalendar.
When I click on the events I want that popup to show all the data filled in to change or to delete the event.

I succeed in adding all in the textboxes but my formatting of the date and time is wrong.

How can I change the format?

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    $("#id").val(calEvent.id);
    $("#date").val(calEvent.start);
    $("#start").val(calEvent.start);
    $("#end").val(calEvent.end);
    $("#allday").val(calEvent.allDay);
    $("#title").val(calEvent.title);
    $("#location").val(calEvent.location);
    $("#description").val(calEvent.description);
    $("#url").val(calEvent.url);
    //open form    
    $(".modalbox").trigger('click');
}
```

I get the values as 2013-09-12 14:00:00

So I want to show the date as 2013-09-12 and the start/end-time as 14:00 e.g.

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$.fullCalendar.formatDate(from, format);` to convert date and time. Some example:

```
$('#calendar-container').fullCalendar({
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view){
        var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(calEvent._start, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss');
        var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(calEvent._end, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss');
        alert('start: ' + start + '; end: ' + end);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As of fullcalendar 2.1.1 formatDate no longer seems to be supported.

Happy to mention the integration of moment.js to fullCalendar.

Read Moment.js [Documentation](http://momentjs.com/), formatting as such:

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // September 16th 2014, 6:38:44 pm
moment().format('dddd');                    // Tuesday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Sep 16th 14
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');
```